# wso2 esb poll files, read data, transform data publish record message

Tags: wso2, integration, tooling, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

My tech req is the following :

1. Poll CSV Files
2. Read Data line by line
3. Transform data to desired format
4. convert to JSON/XML
5. Publish data thru REST/JMS
6. Deploy in WSO2 EI6.1.1

How is this possible in DS Tooling 3.8.0 of WSO2 ?

I know inbound endpoints,mediators,sequences proxy services etc can be used, but cant find a single document/article that helps in doing this.

Where do I start? How do I sequentially execute these steps? Artifacts are independently created, but dont how to automate them to an integration flow.

Appreciate if someone can shed some light.

Comment: it was mentioned that there's no straightforward OOTB way to read files and publish data. Is it still true on 611? Do we have to write a custom class mediator to achieve this?

Comment: Show what you already did.

Comment: I was able to create one inbound-enpoint-FILE with two sequences, success and error. the sequences had log mediator to log simple messages to management console-system logs. Thats all. I couldnt paste the inbound-endpoint xml source here, due to character restrictions.

Comment: There is huge amount of samples in wso2ei distribution. Have a look documentaion. I am sure there is something similar or particularly useful. There is example from yenlo https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-how-to-process-a-csv-file-using-the-smooks-mediator

Comment: Thanks , I was able to follow the example, you sent. once processed by smooks-config, the data is shown as XML type data in the "rootElement". How do we send this rootelement to jms message? Create an endpoint or sequence or mediator or proxy? am clueless.Documentation does not help in orchestrating a whole scenario of components.

Comment: :=) https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-wso2esb-send-message-to-a-jms-endpoint-example-for-activemq

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. But the example doesnt show the data or messagebody binding to the JMS transport. what intermediate steps need to be done, from smooks-config to transportsender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

1. Create empty ESB solution project.
2. Create Proxy-Service.
3. Use Smooks-config  for tranformation of CSV flat data to XML format
4. Create endpoint, for producing JMS messages to JMS queue of ActiveMQ.
5. Use datamapper mediator, if transformation is required
6. Use log mediator , for logging.
7. Use property mediator for setting endpoint related properties.
8. Config - axis2.xml,axis2Client.xml for enabling transport settings on E1611.
9. Export to CAR file, deploy on EI611 management console.
10. Happy Testing!!